# How do I replace a word in my text file using Scanner?

Tags: java, replace, java.util.scanner, words

So the goal of my code is to read the text file in using `Scanner` and then take the user input via text fields.

The scanner will then iterate through the text file trying to find an instance of said user input, if that input is then found, it replaces the word within the text file.

I then write back to the file, with just that one word changed.

My problem is that I have not used Scanner before and going through the docs, I am unsure of how to proceed correctly.

Here is my code so far that activates at the click of a button:

```
    Scanner read = new Scanner("test test.txt");

    //Converting user input from editSerialField to a scanner
    Scanner scEditSerial = new Scanner(editSerialField.getText());
    String scSerial = scEditSerial.nextLine();
    //Converting user input from editLocationField to a scanner
    Scanner scEditLocation = new Scanner(editLocationField.getText());
    String scLocation = scEditSerial.nextLine();

    while (read.hasNextLine())
    {
        //If my text file contains the user input from the text field
        if (read.hasNext(scSerial))
        {
            //Code to replace instance of editSerialField in text file
        }

        //Code to write back to the file
    }
```

How do I use `Scanner` to replace words within a text file? Am I to use a different class to do so?

I'm stuck as to how to proceed with my code, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So *why* do you want to use `Scanner` to read the file? How do you intend to write the file? `PrintWriter` around `FileWriter`? If so, why not read using `BufferedReader` around `FileReader`? --- *FYI:* If all you're doing is reading full lines, `BufferedReader` is **many** times faster than `Scanner`, which is *really slooowwwwww*.

Comment: I want to read all the lines of my file and replace an instance of the user input within the text file with another user input. I was told use `Scanner` would be the best way to scan through the lines and replace a word. I'm unsure as to how to replace words using `Scanner`. I'm new to Java so I don't know what other classes to use.

Comment: You can't *replace words* using `Scanner`. `Scanner` is used for *reading* (aka scanning) input. You're probably too new to have learned about regex yet, so `indexOf()` and `substring()` are probably the methods you're supposed to use to replace text in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using `Scanner` class. as `Scanner` class is used to read only. you can replace the words as below:

```
Path path = Paths.get("test.txt");
Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
content = content.replaceAll("foo", "bar");
Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));
```

Or you can also see `BufferedWriter` or `FileWriter`. You can go through the working example [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/java-transfer-content-from-one-file-to-another/)